# PHP7: Memory leak lefts when I allocate a string with the length from a variable?

Tags: php, php-extension

It confuses me when I allocate a string with the length from a constant int or size_t variable. It'll make memory leak.

On the other hand, it works well when I allocate it with a number. What's going on with it?

```
    PHP_FUNCTION(aa_encrypt64) {
    const char *key = "";  // base64
    char *str = NULL;
    char *datetime = NULL;
    char *private_key = NULL;

    const size_t rtn_len = 32;       
    char rtn[rtn_len];           // char rtn[rtn_len]  leaves memory leak

    int argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
    size_t str_len;
    size_t datetime_len;
    size_t private_key_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(argc, "sss", &str, &str_len, &datetime, &datetime_len, &private_key, &private_key_len) == FAILURE) 
        return;
        md5(str, rtn);
    RETURN_STRINGL(rtn, rtn_len);
}
PHP_FUNCTION(aa_decrypt64)
{
```

Memory leaks ..... 
[image: Memory leaks .....]

```
   PHP_FUNCTION(aa_encrypt64) {
  const char *key = "";  // base64
  char *str = NULL;
  char *datetime = NULL;
  char *private_key = NULL;

  const size_t rtn_len = 32;       
  char rtn[32];           // char rtn[rtn_len]  leaves memory leak

  int argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
  size_t str_len;
  size_t datetime_len;
  size_t private_key_len;

  if (zend_parse_parameters(argc, "sss", &str, &str_len, &datetime, &datetime_len, &private_key, &private_key_len) == FAILURE) 
    return;
  md5(str, rtn);
  RETURN_STRINGL(rtn, rtn_len);
```

}

[image]

Comment: I think you are mistaken, neither of those are heap allocations, and so cannot cause leaks. ```USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0``` in env and run valgrind with leak checking enabled, should give you more useful information.

Comment: I was compiling it on centos 7 in a docker container. And I tried using char rtn[32] and char rtn[rtn_len] once and once again. It showed errors above.   ----> It's ridiculous! It really took me a lot time to debug the `memory leak` error from the unpredictable stack memory allocation. ---> When I was tired, I re-started my virtual machine. And it turns to be working fine.